# All content types are using an incorrect /edit url

Tags: path-aliases

I’ve run into a really strange issue. Just recently every new node I create, of any content type, has a nonsensical /edit url. Instead of /node/[nid]/edit, it’s /using-library/frequently-asked-questions20/edit (and then next one I create will be /using-library/frequently-asked-questions21/edit). The actual alias for the node is /rooms-studios/test. I’m attaching a screenshot. Has anyone seen something like this? What could be causing it?

[image]

The problem was happening in my production environment, but not in my test environment. And then I pulled the production db into test and NOW it's happening in my test env. But I can’t find any sign of that edit url in my db. I found a handful of nodes that were created in 2015 that also have this strange /edit url. When I deleted aliases and cleared caches, it seemed to resolve itself until I did a Bulk Update and then they're back to the weird url.

I'm using Pathauto 7.x-1.2, but there's no setting to update the /edit url and, as I understand it, another submodule is required to change the edit url.

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing [subpathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) would do

Comment: You're right, it's similar to what subpathauto does, but 1. I don't have that module and 2. it's not matching edit urls to their respective subpath; it's using some other path. In the example above, the alias is /rooms-studios/test, so it might make sense if the edit url was /rooms-studios/test/edit, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've figure it out. I had custom code to fix issues with FacetAPI Pretty Paths. In my case, node/42 was a search page with a pathauto pattern (e.g., /test). Because of the custom code, anything that started with node/42 (e.g., node/420, node/4272) would apply the same pattern, event to admin pages, so I was getting urls like /test0/edit and /test72/edit. I updated the issue in case anyone else comes across something similar when working with pretty paths.